# Уместно ли такое употребление

Tags: огэ

> В качестве примера из жизненного опыта приведу роман Достоевского
> "Преступление и наказание".

Логична ли данная часть: в качестве примера - роман.

Comment: не особо логично) но зависит от того что дальше, хотя лучше переформулировать. Там же отдельно литературный источник, и из жизни - они типа разные, в этом фишка. Но может быть ребенок имел ввиду, что читал роман, процесс чтения...

Comment: https://bank-argumentov.info/zhiznennyj-opyt-argumenty-iz-literatury/

Comment: https://dzen.ru/a/Yl3LiHKYIEnprewt

Comment: Нужно указать, чей это жизненный опыт: из моего жизненного опыта, из жизненного опыта литературных героев.

Comment: @Sharon а это обязательно писать? Что будет если не написать?

Comment: Чисто на слух мне кажется, что нужно. Как объяснить? Это что-то вроде информативной недостаточности слова "опыт" в конкретном предложении. Могут посчитать за стилистическую неточность.

Comment: Просто в клише, которые я видела, часто пишут просто "жизненного опыта".

Comment: Чтобы определить правильность предложения, в вопросе нужно указать тему сочинения и привести контекст.  К примеру, в разделе "Нравственные и этические проблемы" есть тема "Опыт и ошибки".  Литературные аргументы используются в каждой теме, в том числе и в этой. (Литература является дополнительным источником для расширения личного жизненного опыта  человека,)  Но нужна  корректная формулировка конкретного предложения.  Именно в  ЭТОМ предложении нужно указать, чей это жизненный опыт.  Например: В качестве примера из жизненного опыта литературных героев приведу роман...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уместно. Возможно, конкретный роман сыграл некую (важную?) роль в жизни рассказчика; да со мной так было: с "ПиН" для меня начался Достоевский, который моей душе более "наше всё", чем Пушкин.

А в качестве примера можно привести всё что угодно, буквально. Случай из жизни? А почему бы не случиться книге, которая перевернёт тебя?

Так что логично.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, литературное произведение не считается примером жизненного опыта.
Примером жизненного опыта  могут служить:

исторические факты;
общественно значимые вопросы, обсуждаемые в обществе (в СМИ);
результаты личных наблюдений (частные случаи).
Если вы приведете пример из литературы и далее будет писать о нем, это будет считаться литературным примером.
Однако, если вас жизненный опыт совпадает  с романом  художественной литературы, вы можете по ходу повествования в качестве сравнения привести из художественной литературы.

Comment: Тут вы не правы. Точно знаю от экспертов, что литературный опыт входит в жизненный. Так что тут нет неточностей.  Вопрос только во фразе.

Comment: Чем отличается литературный пример от жизненного?

Comment: Тут не в отличиях дело. А в том,что любой литературный пример считается примером из жизненного опыта.

Comment: Тогда зачем приводить в качестве аргумента два примера: жизненный и литературный?

Comment: Не понимаю вас зовсим.

Comment: В качестве аргумента приводятся два примера: один из литературы, другой из жизненно опыта. Если привести пример жизненного опыта из литературы, это будет литературный пример.

Comment: Лучше всего сделать, как сказала Шарон. То что говорится в статьях по ссылке, это не аргумент из жизненно опыта, а обоснование своего   отношения к позиции автора.